# Face normals on dynamic geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to create a vertex animation for a mesh.
Just imagine a vertex shader, but in software instead of hardware.

Basically what I do is to apply a transformation matrix to each vertex. The mesh it's ok but the normals doesn't look good at all.
I've try to use both **computeVertexNormals()** and **computeFaceNormals()** but it just doesn't work.

The following code is the one I used for the animation (***initialVertices*** are the initial vertices generated by the CubeGeometry):

```
for (var i=0;i<mesh1.geometry.vertices.length; i++)
{
    var vtx=initialVertices[i].clone();
    var dist = vtx.y;

    var rot=clock.getElapsedTime() - dist*0.02;

    matrix.makeRotationY(rot);

    vtx.applyMatrix4(matrix);
    mesh1.geometry.vertices[i]=vtx;
}
mesh1.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
```

Here there're two examples, one working correctly with ***CanvasRenderer***:

http://kile.stravaganza.org/lab/js/dynamic/canvas.html

and the one that doesn't works in ***WebGL***:

http://kile.stravaganza.org/lab/js/dynamic/webgl.html

Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing several things.

(1) You need to set the ambient reflectance of the material. It is reasonable to set it equal to the diffuse reflectance, or `color`.

```
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {
    color:0xff0000,
    ambient:0xff0000
} );
```

(2) If you are moving vertices, you need to update centroids, face normals, and vertex normals -- in the proper order. See the source code.

```
mesh1.geometry.computeCentroids();
mesh1.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
mesh1.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
```

(3) When you are using `WebGLRenderer`, you need to set the required update flags:

```
mesh1.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
mesh1.geometry.normalsNeedUpdate = true;
```

Tip: is it a good idea to avoid `new` and `clone` in tight loops.

three.js r.63

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfect :)
I've updated the webgl version and works like charm
http://kile.stravaganza.org/lab/js/dynamic/webgl.html
About the new/clone it was just a fast proof of concept so I didn't pay so much attention to resources management/perfomance, but will try to fix that in the future ;)